# Is javascript compiled on the client and server when using Chrome & Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, compilation, v8

I've always viewed script languages (javascript, vscript, any kind of "script") as interpreted and therefore slower than compiled languages like C and C++.

*"JavaScript is an interpreted language, with optional JIT-compilation support. In older implementations (e.g. Internet Exlorer 8 and earlier, Firefox prior to 3.5), JavaScript was a purely interpreted language. This means that scripts execute without preliminary compilation, i.e. without conversion of the script text into system-dependent machine code."* -- http://www.javascripter.net/faq/whatisja.htm

In reading through the following, apparently google chrome (using V8) compiles javascript on the client:

*"Here’s how it works. First, V8 defers compilation of JavaScript functions until immediately before they are executed the first time (to reduce the overall time spent compiling). Next, pieces of code that are executed very often are compiled a second time by a specialized optimizing compiler. This second pass makes takes more time, but thanks to many advanced optimization techniques, it delivers much faster code."* -- http://thenextweb.com/google/2014/02/13/google-speeds-chrome-compiling-javascript-background/

It sounds like on V8, javascript is now a compiled language since they compile each function into machine code as soon as they see a function and before it is executed.

Additionally, this https://gist.github.com/spion/3049314 also appears to indicate (for this test case) that javascript on V8 is even faster than compiled C++ doing the same thing.

Does this mean that javascript is in fact compiled into machine code before it is executed on both the client and the server (since node.js uses V8) and therefore runs as complied machine code (like java, C, or C++ are) instead of interpreted code (like Perl, PHP, or Powershell are) with the related execution speed benefits?

Interpreted languages:

*"The main disadvantage of interpreting is a much slower speed of
program execution compared to direct machine code execution on the
host CPU"*  -- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreted_language

Compiled languages:

*"Compiled languages are always supposed to be fast because of their direct execution by the computer."* -- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/696764/Differences-between-compiled-and-Interpreted-Langu

Comment: Related, maybe: https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Optimization-killers

Comment: It depends on the implementation, but JavaScript is actually interpreted, compiled to a lower level language, like C, and then compiled into insturctions.

Comment: @user3417400, the V8 engine does not have an interpreter, it goes straight to compilation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, in 2014, everyone compiles JavaScript to native code using various strategies to optimize the code. There are even standards like [asm.js](http://asmjs.org/) to allow to compile JavaScript in such a way that the resulting code is at least as fast as code written in C/C++ or Java.

As always, the performance that you get in the end really depends on the optimizations and your code. Just as it's easy to write slow code in Java or C++, you can also write something that no automatic optimizer in the world can fix.

Comment: Spot on with the second paragraph. :)

Also, the internally compiled JS is much like Java bytecode, where it is basically an IR that is automatically optimized as its run (JIT optimization).

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is compiled but compiling itself doesn't make anything fast, it's the optimizations the compiler does.

The fact that V8 doesn't have an interpreter at all unlike other engines is a design trade-off - it doesn't mean that interpreting is slower than compiled code that is unoptimized.

Comment: @ChrisGciso The code generated by V8's non-optimizing compiler is equal speed or slower than SpiderMonkey's bytecode interpreter. Interpreting doesn't mean "english words" at all..

Comment: @ChrisGciso I meant that interpreter doesn't work with the source code like you implied - even the naivest interpreters will at least parse it, let alone world class interpreters like [spidermonkey](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey/Internals).

Comment: I love how the only answer by someone with code committed to Chromium/V8 is the most downvoted one.

Comment: @ChrisGciso the most typical case is that the input source code is parsed into an AST and bytecode is generated from the AST. The bytecode is then interpreted, this is long past "english words" representation.

Comment: Compiling removes the interpreter overhead, which I assume is what he means by "speed benefits".  It also, however, adds an up-front cost (compiling to machine code is likely to be more expensive than compiling to some other internal representation).  That said, other optimizations will usually outweigh any of those effects in a language as complicated as javascript.